# Any way to hide an object while keeping its form?

Tags: light

I wanted to rotate within a room but rotating causes me to see the outside walls

So i wanted to hide the walls but still get the way the light is shaped by the holes in the wall (Light placed outside)

to cast onto the interior while i am working in Eevee

So far the moment I hide the geo, the light shape the holes in wall makes, will be gone too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mix with transparency on the basis of light paths/is shadow ray, and you can make the wall invisible to the camera, but visible to your lights:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to copy paste this material onto multiple meshes to make it Quick if applying on multiple meshes?

Also is there a way to toggle this on/off with ease like visibility can?

Comment: @jin098 absolutely, look into the use of "node groups" to easily paste this into other materials.  Exact usage (animated, or based off some other characteristic) can be built into it; this is just the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you so much Nathan you absolute god!!